# Hamburger Icon shifts left when opening menu

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive

My React site has a responsive header which will show a hamburger menu on the right of the header on a mobile device.
Clicking this hamburger icon *does* show a menu beneath the header but the icon shifts further to the right outside of the header. It is still rendered but just too far on the right when the menu opens, instead of staying in the same place.

My React file is as follows:

return (

```
    <h1 className="Logo">Emence</h1>

    <CSSTransition
        in={!isSmallScreen || isNavVisible}
        timeout={350}
        classNames="NavAnimation"
        unmountOnExit
    >
        <nav>
            <div className="Nav">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/">Werken</a>
                <a href="/">Over ons</a>
                <a href="/">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </CSSTransition>

    <button onClick={toggleNav} className="Burger">
        <b style={{color: "white"}}>≡</b>
    </button>

</header>
```

);

And the (responsive) CSS:

```
.Header {
    z-index: 1;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position: relative;
    top: 0; /* Stick it to the top */
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "logo nav";
    background-color: #282c34;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: auto;

}

.Logo {
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 40px;

    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-area: logo;
}

.Nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: nav;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.Burger {
    display: none;
    grid-area: burger;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-self: end;
    font-size: 40px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .Header {
        grid-template-areas: "logo burger" "nav nav";
    }

    .Nav {
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
        grid-template-columns: none;
        grid-row-gap: 20px;

        width: 100vw;

        padding: 30px 0 30px;
        background: rgba(40, 44, 47, 0.95);
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    }

    .Burger {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the inline display of the burger is what's causing the shift. Try setting it to block.

Comment: That did not seem to work. Neither does padding and margin. The odd thing is that only the VW of the .Nav class seems to work, but this changes the fullscreen width of the menu.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML(from the inspector)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is to remove the child div (.nav) from the parent element which is not in the grid. I simply removed that div from the markup and added the .nav class to the nav element.

```
    <h1 className="Logo">Emence</h1>

    <CSSTransition
        in={!isSmallScreen || isNavVisible}
        timeout={350}
        classNames="NavAnimation"
        unmountOnExit
    >
        <nav class="Nav">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/">Werken</a>
                <a href="/">Over ons</a>
                <a href="/">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </CSSTransition>

    <button onClick={toggleNav} className="Burger">
        <b style={{color: "white"}}>≡</b>
    </button>

</header>
```

https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/WNQjKWa